# Eliminate duplicate entries in sql

Tags: sql

I want to truncate duplicate rows but `Qty` should be added.

I have a table filled with data,

```
Item Qty MinQty MaxQty
ABC  10  20     50
XYZ  12  30     40
ABC  15  20     50
```

I want the result like,

```
Item Qty MinQty MaxQty
ABC  25  20     50
XYZ  12  30     40
```

Kindly help me to write the query for the same...

Comment: What is your requirement ??You want to Update and Delete duplicate  row also or just want to show data??

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT Item, SUM(Qty), MIN(MinQty), MAX(MaxQty)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ITem;
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is right, but you would also want to give the derived columns names:

```
SELECT Item, SUM(Qty) as Qty, MIN(MinQty) as MinQty, MAX(MaxQty) as MaxQty
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ITem;
```